# Averaging a total in mySQL

Tags: mysql

My table looks like

```
person_id  | car_id | miles
------------------------------
    1      |   1    |  100
    1      |   2    |  200
    2      |   3    | 1000 
    2      |   4    |  500
```

I need to total the miles for each person and then average those totals.

There are 2 people - person 1 drove 300 miles, person 2 drove 1500 miles.

(300+1500)/2 = 900 average number of miles driven per person.

Which is the same thing as totaling the number of miles and dividing by the number of people.

I cannot figure out a mySQL statement that will either give me the average across people or give me total the number of miles and the number of people so I can do the division.

Comment: I haven't had homework in 20 years. I could probably dig up an old homework assignment but it would be in FORTRAN. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Total per person:

```
SELECT person_id, SUM(miles) FROM table GROUP BY person_id
```

Average

```
SELECT SUM(miles) / COUNT(DISTINCT person_id) FROM table
```

These should work

Answer (score 2):

As soon as the `person_id` and `miles` are indexed, the fastest method will be this:

```
SELECT  SUM(miles) /
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    (
                SELECT  DISTINCT person_id
                FROM    mytable
                ) q
        )
FROM    mytable
```

This will allow using two separate indexes for `miles` and `person_id`, the first one being in no certain order, the second one using `INDEX FOR GROUP BY`.

The sum will be calculated in no certain order and requires only a single index scan, without table lookup.

The subquery will be executed once using `INDEX FOR GROUP BY` and cached.

The final division, hence, will be a single operation over a precalculated sum and precalculated `COUNT`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AVG(`miles_per_person`)
FROM
   (SELECT SUM(`miles`) `miles_per_person`
      FROM `persons`
  GROUP BY `person_id`) `a`
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrected: just as the other author:

```
select sum(miles)/count(distinct person_id) avg_miles from tablename;
```

Comment: Attention... Need to define this total_miles alias

Comment: you never assign the `total_miles` alias